# UTF8.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes returns different results on Windows and Linux

Tags: .net-core

I'm running into an issue where I get different results on Linux (tested with Ubuntu) and Windows.

I created https://github.com/benrobot/EncodingTests to showcase the issue I'm experiencing.

On Windows, calling `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("’")` returns the correct 3 bytes (`0xE2, 0x80, 0x99` per https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) but on Linux (tested on Ubuntu) the
returned bytes correspond to � (`0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD` per https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

Shouldn't .NET Core behave the same on both operating systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out file encoding was the problem. My .cs file was ANSI (Windows-1252) encoded. When I added UTF8 encoded versions of the same test they passed on both operating systems.

Here's a screenshot showing Notepad++ with circles around the file encoding:
[image]

The solution was to use Notepad++ menu option *Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8* to convert the file to a format acceptable in Linux.